# Ncurses with non-blocking input and fork

Tags: c, fork, pipe, semaphore, ncurses

I am having problems to make a proper read-write between process with fork() and ncurses. I have a process (let me call it son) that control the input on the application, and also i have a process (the parent) that control the logic of the app.

My problem is that i write inside the pipe to send information from son to parent but parent doesn't read anything.

Due to non-blocking nature, i added waits and signals to mutualy exclude process while read and write.

Let me show you some code :)

```
    //---- pipes, read i write no bloquejants ---------
    int flags_f0 = fcntl(pip_fill[0],F_GETFL);
    int flags_f1 = fcntl(pip_fill[1],F_GETFL);
    int flags_p0 = fcntl(pip_pare[0],F_GETFL);
    int flags_p1 = fcntl(pip_pare[1],F_GETFL);
    int flags_read = fcntl(0,F_GETFL);
    int flags_write = fcntl(1,F_GETFL);


    fcntl(pip_fill[0],F_SETFL,flags_f0 | O_NONBLOCK);
    fcntl(pip_fill[1],F_SETFL,flags_f1 | O_NONBLOCK);
    fcntl(pip_pare[0],F_SETFL,flags_p0 | O_NONBLOCK);
    fcntl(pip_pare[1],F_SETFL,flags_p1 | O_NONBLOCK);
    fcntl(0,F_SETFL,flags_read | O_NONBLOCK);
    fcntl(1,F_SETFL,flags_write | O_NONBLOCK);
    //-------------------------------------------------

    //---- semàfors ----
    int id_Sem;

    id_Sem = shmget (IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    if (id_Sem == -1)
    {
        write(2,"Error!\n",7);
        Sortir(&ll_a_r,&ll_res,&ll_mis,&ll_n_mis,&c,&c_write);
        exit (0);
    }


if(SEM_constructor(&sem1) < 0)
{
       shmctl(id_Sem, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    }

    if(SEM_constructor(&sem2) < 0)
{
        shmctl(id_Sem, IPC_RMID, NULL);
        SEM_destructor (&sem1);
    }

    SEM_init (&sem1, 0);
    SEM_init (&sem2, 0);

//------------------



//la primera vegada que entri en el fill posarem les següents dades a la var valor

Afegir_Cadena(&c,"M0:");    //on M0: menú principal

pantalla(w);
pinta_menu_principal(w,a_menus);    //pinta el menú principal per pantalla

pid = fork();

switch (pid)
{
    case -1: //ERROR
        write(2,"Error!\n",7);
        Sortir(&ll_a_r,&ll_res,&ll_mis,&ll_n_mis,&c,&c_write);
        exit(-1);
            break;

    case 0: //FILL
        close(pip_fill[0]); //tanquem l'extrem de la pipe que no usem (la de lectura)
        close(pip_pare[1]); //tanquem l'extrem de la pipe que no usem (la d'escriptura)

        while(1)
        {
                cc = getch();
                if(cc != ERR)
            {
                if(cc == 0x0A)
                {
                    printf("Enter [%s]\n", Retorna_Cad(&c_write));
                    SEM_wait (&sem1);
                    tmp = write(pip_fill[1],Retorna_Cad(&c_write),Retorna_Longitud(&c_write) + 1);  //el fill escriu a la pipe la variable c
                    SEM_signal (&sem1);                                                     //longitud + 1: el +1 es per el \0
                    //printf("Ret: %d",tmp);
                    Esborra_Cadena(&c_write);
                    actualitza_pantalla(w);
                }
                else
                {
                    Afegir_Caracter(&c_write,cc);
                    cc = ERR;
                }
            }

    //***** READ PARE *********
            SEM_wait (&sem2);
            nbytes = read(pip_pare[0],valor,256); //el fill llegeix de la pipe la var un cop ha estat tractada per el pare
            SEM_signal (&sem2);

            if (nbytes > -1)
            {   
                Inserir_Cad(&c,valor);
                //tractar el missatge del pare
        Tractar_Missatge_del_Pare(&ll_mis,&ll_res,&c,w,a_menus,&ll_a_r);
            }
        }
        break;

    default: //PARE
        close(pip_fill[1]); //tanquem l'extrem de la pipe que no usem (la d'escriptura)
        close(pip_pare[0]); //tanquem l'extrem de la pipe que no usem (la de lectura)

        while(1)
        {
            temps_inici = (float)clock();
            SEM_wait (&sem1);
            nbytes = read(pip_fill[0],valor,256);//el pare llegeix de la pipe la var c 
            SEM_signal (&sem1);

            if (nbytes > -1 || tmp > 0)
            {   //vol dir que hem llegit algo per la pipe pip_fill
                tmp++;
                Inserir_Cad(&c,valor);
                Tractar_Missatge_del_Fill (&ll_mis,&c,&ll_n_mis,w);
                SEM_wait (&sem2);
                   write(pip_pare[1],Retorna_Cad(&c),Retorna_Longitud(&c) + 1); //el pare escriu a la pipe la var tractada
                SEM_signal (&sem2);

                actualitza_pantalla(w);
            }


            temps_final = (float)clock();
            temps_per_bucle = (float)(temps_final - temps_inici) / (float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

            Esborra_Cadena(&aux);
            Afegir_Float (&aux, temps_per_bucle);
            //mvwprintw(w[4],8,1,Retorna_Cad(&aux));

        }
        break;
    }
}
else
    {
    exit(1);    //login incorrecte --> sortim de l'aplicacio
}
```

I didn't post all the code, only the main part where read+writes are done with waits and signals.

Maybe i am losing something that i can't see right now. The fact is that son will write on 'pipe_fill' and parent will read from this pipe, also, parent will write on 'pipe_pare' and then, son will read from it to send information.

Also i am using ncurses to make all the window drawing.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Why don't you just use blocking I/O instead of messing with semaphores? Your parent locks the semaphore, tries to read, fails, unlocks, locks again, tries to read etc, and the poor son never gets a chance to write anything because it's always waiting on `SEM_wait`.

Comment: if i only block the O/I, can parent read from the pipe before son ends his write to the same pipe ? I think that i can put a sleep(1) at the end of parent process, but i am not allowed to use this function for this application :(

Comment: Blocking I/O will do exactly what you want. Just throw all your semaphores and fcntls away. You don't do this stuff when you use stdio and you don't need it here. `read` will wait until some data is available on the pipe. Not necessarily all 256 bytes, but at least 1 byte.

Comment: I agree with you, but i need a non-blocking system, i mean, i don't need that parents waits for something in the pipe. I think in this case i need the fcntls and semaphores because mutual exclusion. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You don't need the semaphores because you don't need mutual exclusion. You might think you want to establish order: writer first, reader second. This is not mutual exclusion and it can't be done with mutual exclusion mechanisms. But you don't need order either, the pipe will magically do everything by itself. If you don't want the reader to wait, then go non-blocking (but then why you had it waiting on a sema?) If you go non-blocking, the reader must have some job to do when there's no input on the pipe. It also needs to know when it must stop doing that job and go back to check the pipe.

Comment: So, do you think if a put a 'sleep(1)' at the end of the parents code it will work (in a non-blocking enviroment) ? My intention is to have a non-bloking behaviour and only waits a little if there is someone writing before the others read. What i fear is son starts to write 100 bytes, and after 20 bytes writen, then the parent read and only found 20 bytes of the 100.

Comment: The reader needs to loop until it reads the entire message. The writer needs to loop until it writes the entire message. You cannot assume you can read or write the entire message in one go. Generally, if you find yourself calling `sleep` in order to fix broken IPC, you're doing something wrong and IPC will stay broken. Of course if there's a specific protocol requirement to wait a specified amount of time, then `sleep` is OK.

Comment: 2 Thinks: 1.- If i remove the sema from the code, the parent didnt read anything from the son, i dont know why :(  2.- About behaviour of the code, i think another aproach needs to be taken, i mean, i append all i read from the pipe to a temporal buffer, and periodically check this buffer to get a complete message to be processed.  My big concern is that parent 'without' sema didnt read anything :(

Comment: The parent didn't read anything because the son didn't write anything. You have to wait for the son to write something. You can do this by using the blocking IO API provided by the OS, or you can simulate it by using non-blocking IO plus some kind external waiting/signaling mechanism. The end result is the same, you have to wait. I suggest you start with blocking IO, and as soon as it's working, think about how you modify it to non-blocking. As for (2) this is the right approach.

Comment: Right now i have no semaphores on the code, and write from the son tells me he write N bytes (the same i pass to it) but parent, without semaphores, didnt read anything.

Comment: Are you using blocking or non-blocking IO? You need to start using blocking. There's no point in using non-blocking IO and then wait for IO completion using some external waiting mechanism. Blocking IO provides all the synchronisation you need. If you already use blocking, please show a complete minimal compilable example of the problem.

Comment: if i have blocking IO which is controled by son, the son will be unable to read data from parent in a regular basis, so i need that cc = getch() to be non-blocking. Also, i am using ncurses, and i if i use 'read' function for some reason didn't work.

Comment: OK now you have a simple deadlock. The parent waits for the child to finish writing, but the child is waiting for the parent. If you will use some other mechanism for waiting, the deadlock will not go away. You need to decide who is the client and who is the server. The client starts by asking a question, then waits for an answer;  the server starts by waiting for a question, then processes it and writes the answer.

Comment: But with NO sema and non-blocking IO, i think there are no posible deadlocks, because any write or read makes the execution to stop. I dont know why parent didnt recieve anything.

Comment: There are no deadlocks but there is no synchronisation either. You are not guaranteed to get to read *after* someone else have written something. You need to sequence things. First one side writes, then the other side reads. Then the other side writes, and the first side reads. Hence you need the first side to do write/read, and the second side to do read/write, in this order and no other. Then blocking IO will magically arrange things to happen in the right order.

Comment: Ok, i will try to put SEM_init (&sem1, 1); (note '1') to make all sema unlocked. I think with this i will achieve synchronization:  The son will read parent. When the son take some input, it will write to parent, then parent will write to son. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I'm giving up. There must be another way to say **do not use semaphores, they won't help you** but I can't see it.

Comment: Ok, please explain how can i achieve a parent that will read son's data and a socket data in the same loop without waiting for the son's and socket's data. The fact here is that with or without semaphores, son writes into the pipe, but parent's doesn't see anything, and i dont know why.

Answer (score 1):

OK so here's the code I had in mind.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  int pipePC[2];
  int pipeCP[2];

  pipe(pipePC);
  pipe(pipeCP);

  char buf[11];
  int n;

  switch (fork()) {
  case -1:
    exit (1);
    break;
  case 0: /* child */
    close(pipePC[1]);
    close(pipeCP[0]);
    while (1) { /* read, then write */
        n = read(pipePC[0], buf, 10); /* read the question */
        if (n > 0) {
            buf[n] = 0;
            printf ("child got '%s'\n", buf); /* calculate the answer here */
            write(pipeCP[1], "foobar", 6); /* write the answer */
        }
        else {
            printf ("child got nothing\n");
            exit (1);
        }
        sleep(2); /* only to slow down the output */
    }
    break;
  default: /* parent */
    close(pipePC[0]);
    close(pipeCP[1]);
    while (1) { /* write, then read */
        write(pipePC[1], "barfoo", 6); /* ask a question */
        n = read(pipeCP[0], buf, 10); /* get the answer */
        if (n > 0) {
            buf[n] = 0;
            printf ("parent got '%s'\n", buf);
        }
        else {
            printf ("parent got nothing\n");
            exit (1);
        }
        sleep(3); /* only to slow down the output */
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: With this code, if you block the son waiting for input, the parent is still looping ?

Comment: No. In your original code both parent and child wait for the other to finish writing, and so they do in my code. If you want you can make I/O non-blocking on one or both sides, just remove the calls to `exit` after the "got nothing" message. It will still work, no semaphores required. They will sometimes print "got nothing", and sometimes print parts of the message or several messages together, like "rfoobarfoo". But you shouldn't rely on being able to read the entire message with one `read` call anyway.

Comment: if i only remove the `exit`, it will not grant me non-bloking behaviour for the parent if son is waiting for input, because if there is nothing to read on the pipe, parent will wait until it is. I need that parent still looping if there is no data from the son.

Comment: You need to add the `fcntl` for non-blocking input too of course.

Comment: And then, if you imagine i remove only the semaphores in my initial code, why parent didn't recieve anything from the son if son is writing correctly to the pipe ?